# How to make Oleana appear in Crown Tundra?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, pokemon-crown-tundra

There are reports of Oleana appearing in the Old cementary. From what I can tell online, the requirements are:

- Finish the Crown Tundra story content
- Receive the tip from Peonie referencing her at the graveyard
- Only appears at night time

I have done the above, and she is still not appearing. I have been checking about every 30 min from 9pm to 11:15pm. Also random stuff done: battled and beat Peony in the Max Raid Lair, reached Master Rank in Battle Tower in both Singles and Doubles, completed the Isle of Armor story, completed all three Pokedexes, and participated in a Galarian Star tournament.

Are there any other requirements that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have meet all the requirements needed in order for Oleana to appear. However, based on information from various articles ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonSwordAndShield/comments/jgnrmd/oleana_in_crown_tundra/), [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/259372-pokemon-sword/79111193), and [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/switch/259372-pokemon-sword/answers/575221-why-wont-oleana-appear-in-crown-tundra)), Oleana's appearance in the graveyard appears to be a random chance.

It would seem a majority of plays will simply get her to appear on their first try. If she does not appear, all three of the articles I have linked state that she will eventually appear after attempting a few days.